# Can't download from launchpad

Tags: launchpad

When I try to download some files from launchpad.net my browser displays page full of different strange characters. I can see that last download was today but I am not able to download it. I am able to download files from different projects but not that one. Here is the link: [gcc-arm-embedded-misc](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded-misc/native-build-tools/20140701)

[image: Thats what I see when I want to download]

Comment: Please add a screenshot for better understanding..

Comment: Thats what I can see when I click to download  **prebuilt-native-tools.tar.lzma**

Comment: I also have the same problem although i can download easily using `chromium`..it should be a firefox issue..i am not good with GUI tools..hope someone can help you....

Comment: Is there any way to download it from terminal?

Comment: Sure..thats very easy..just do `wget https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded-misc/native-build-tools/20140701/+download/prebuilt-native-tools.tar.lzma` ..will be downloaded in the current directory..

Comment: Ok I wonder how u can download it using chromium cause in terminal I get: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-03-26 23:11:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: can you download now?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded it.

Answer (score 3):

The server reports MIME type `text/plain` in the [HTTP `Content-Type` header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) and Firefox diligently interprets and displays the file content as such. The server behaviour is a [known bug in Launchpad itself](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/645924).

You can circumvent the issue

- with the entries "Save as…" or "Copy link address"¹ in the context menu of the download link,
- by dragging the link text to a writeable directory in a file manager, that supports HTTP resources, like Nautilus.

A side note concerning the reported behaviour of Chrome/Chromium: web browsers shouldn't care about file extensions to determine file types according to [RFC 1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html). They should only care about the MIME string sent in the HTTP response header. If a browser disregards that string in favour of file extensions or content type sniffing, they may be doing something useful for the user *in most situations*, but they're violating [RFC 1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) in the process.

¹ Plus an HTTP client, that doesn't try to display file content, like `wget`, `curl`, or [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/downthemall/).

Comment: On the funny side, my Firefox process just blew up its reserved memory size to a whooping 3.8 GiB while trying to display the file mentioned in the question.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would simply be to right click the link and click on "Save Link As".

Comment: This is a hack..it will not address the real problem and solution..

Comment: Its not a hack. There is no lzma extension in firefox. I suppose, you could say it is a firefox bug.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think your comment addresses the problem clearly..you should put that as an answer..

Comment: @heemayl: Alright. Done!